# Authenticity of narration in Musnad Ahmad

Tags: hadith, authenticity

Can someone share the authenticity of this narration:

> حدثنا ‏ ‏يحيى بن إسحاق ‏ ‏حدثنا ‏ ‏ابن لهيعة ‏ ‏عن ‏ ‏قيس بن الحجاج ‏
> ‏عن ‏ ‏حنش الصنعاني ‏ ‏عن ‏ ‏ابن عباس ‏ ‏عن ‏ ‏عبد الله بن مسعود ‏
> ‏رضي الله عنهما ‏ ‏أنه كان مع رسول الله ‏ ‏صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ ‏ليلة
> الجن فقال له النبي ‏ ‏صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ ‏يا ‏ ‏عبد الله ‏ ‏أمعك ماء
> قال معي ‏ ‏نبيذ ‏ ‏في ‏ ‏إداوة ‏ ‏فقال اصبب علي فتوضأ قال فقال النبي ‏
> ‏صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ ‏يا ‏ ‏عبد الله بن مسعود ‏ ‏شراب وطهور ‏
>
> Narrated by Abdullah bin Masoud (May God be pleased with him):  He was
> with the Messenger of Allah peace be upon him on the night of the jinn
> when he asked him if he had water. He answered that he had wine in a
> pot. Mohammed said: Pour me some to do ablution and he did. [The]
> Prophet peace be upon him [said]: "O Abdullah bin Masood it is a drink
> and a purifier."
>
> [Musnad Ahmad 3594](http://www.webcitation.org/61Fj1P8sK)

Answer (score 3):

The given chain has weakness because of Abdullah Ibn Lahi'a. The translation is also wrong just like your [previous](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/68780/20218) question, as the hadith talks about *Nabidh* نبيذ not wine. This is also recorded in [Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/1/118-119) in the first book.